# How do I programmatically set a filter in a FPM list UIBB

Tags: abap, webdynpro

In Floorplan Manager I want to programmatically set the filter of a column in the list view.

I can turn filtering on by doing the following:

```
  method if_fpm_guibb_list~get_definition.

    data:
      structure  type ref to cl_abap_structdescr,
      components type cl_abap_structdescr=>included_view.

    field-symbols:
      <component>   like line of components.

    eo_field_catalog ?= cl_abap_tabledescr=>describe_by_name( gc_itm_table ).    
    structure ?= eo_field_catalog->get_table_line_type( ).    
    components = structure->get_included_view( ).

    loop at components assigning <component>.

      append initial line to et_field_description assigning <description>.
      <description>-name = <component>-name.
      <description>-allow_filter = abap_true.

    endloop.
  endmethod.
```

However at the moment I can't find where I can programmatically set what that filter is as I could do in ALV.

Is this even possible?

Comment: If you do [cross-post](http://scn.sap.com/message/16217692#16217692), please at least link the posts with each other...

Comment: @vwegert will do so in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered on [SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3796202) - credit Ulrich Miller

> Unfortunately such a functionality is currently not supported, i. e.
>   filter rules cannot be set programmatically but only by the user